# Chain a JdbcCursorItemReader and a StoredProcedureItemReader in the same Sprin Batch step

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch

I want to chain two readers : JdbcCursorItemReader and a StoredProcedureItemReader. The result of the first reader will be passed as parameters to the stored procedure, the results of this stored procedure will then be passed to some writer.
My two readers will be somthing like this :

```
<bean id="centralItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DS" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[
                    select num1, num2
                    from table1
                ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="batch.model.PubRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="publishProcedureReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DS" />
        <property name="procedureName" value="PUBLISH"/>
        <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <!-- first parameter from the previous reader result -->
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="value_here"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
           <!-- Second parameter from the previous reader result -->
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="value_here"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="batch.model.ProcedureRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How can I pass the results from the first reader to the second one ?
In my understanding a spring batch step contains only one reader, one processor, and one writer

Is there some way to chain these two readers as a composite reader in the same step ?

Comment: Use a processor or just write a query that calls the stored procedure (it is just a SQL call in the end).

Comment: How many rows would your first query return? If it's a single row and you just need the values of `num1` and `num2` to be injected in the parameters of your stored procedure, then you don't need an item reader for that, a simple tasklet that executes the query and stores the values in the execution context is enough. If your query returns multiple rows and you want to call the stored procedure for each row, then you can implement the driving query pattern where an item processor calls your stored procedure for each item.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine the first query can return many rows :) thanks for the guidance, I will try to implement it, any ressources in the web on how it can be done ? I am a beginner in Spring Batch